# Cannot split pandas dataframe column due to NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have the following messy dataframe:

[image]

```
print(df[7:9].to_dict())
{'Scheduled': {7: 'END 3RD: 0-0, 3 Out917YankeesNYY918RaysTB', 8: 'TOP 3RD: 1-2, 2 Out915Blue JaysTOR916Red SoxBOS'}, 'Open': {7: '+115-135', 8: '-115-105'}, 'Best Odds': {7: '+125ML+130ML', 8: '+120ML-125ML'}, '% of Bets': {7: '55%45%', 8: '31%69%'}, '% of Money': {7: '34%66%', 8: nan}, 'Diff': {7: '+21%', 8: nan}, 'Bets': {7: 12445, 8: 6178}}

df[7:9]
Scheduled   Open    Best Odds   % of Bets   % of Money  Diff    Bets
7   END 3RD: 0-0, 3 Out917YankeesNYY918RaysTB   +115-135    +125ML+130ML    55%45%  34%66%  +21%    12445
8   TOP 3RD: 1-2, 2 Out915Blue JaysTOR916Red SoxBOS -115-105    +120ML-125ML    31%69%  NaN NaN 6178

df.dtypes
Scheduled     object
Open          object
Best Odds     object
% of Bets     object
% of Money    object
Diff          object
Bets           int64
dtype: object
```

**Edit**: I tried to paste the output of `print(df[7:9].to_dict())` in a notebook cell to run the code, and received the error `NameError: name 'nan' is not defined`. Not sure how else to share reproducible example?

We are iterating through `df`, attempting to split some of these columns up into 2 columns, as each column carries data for 2 teams. The `NaN` values are causing problems, and we cannot use `math.isnan()` because `% of Money` is a column of strings and `math.isnan()` seems to return an error for strings. The following code is breaking on us:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    string = row['% of Money']
    if len(string) == 2:
        num_pair_perc_mon = [string[0], string[1]]
    else:
        split_index = min([i for i, char in enumerate(string) if char in ['%']])
        num_pair_perc_mon = [string[:split_index + 1], string[split_index + 1:]]
    
    print(num_pair_perc_mon)
    df.at[i, 't1_pct_money'] = num_pair_perc_mon[0]
    df.at[i, 't2_pct_money'] = num_pair_perc_mon[1]
```

with output:

[image]

How can we successfully split `% of Money` into 2 columns, handling the NaN that we are provided with in the dataframe?

Comment: `nan` is completely fine. `from numpy import nan` will make it not undefined.

Comment: `min([i for i, char in enumerate(string) if char in ['%']])` is an issue since `min` won't work on an empty collection. How do you expect handle this when there is nothing in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract all values that match the pattern. Then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to convert the capture groups from rows to columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '% of Money': {7: '34%66%', 8: nan}
})

df[['t1_pct_money', 't2_pct_money']] = (
    df['% of Money'].str.extractall(r'([+-]?\d+%)').unstack()
)
```

`df`:

```
  % of Money t1_pct_money t2_pct_money
7     34%66%          34%          66%
8        NaN          NaN          NaN
```

---

Regex details:

```
[+-]?\d+%
```

- Match a single character present in the list [+-]

  - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `+-` matches a single character in the list `+-` (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `%` matches the character `%` literally (case sensitive)